# How to hide source code tab from user in github?

Tags: github

I have a repo in GitHub (private), all my source code is there.

I recently hire a QA to test the system and find some bugs. I want from him to open bugs and issues on github so my developer will fix them and update statuses.

The problem is I don't want QA to able to see the source code.

I think to open different repo just for QA to put the bugs there, but now my developer is working on two repo which the same.

Is there a nice solution for this problem?  maybe some configuration that allow me to hide the source for the user? or website that show the issue and allow to manage them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a clean solution (as in having a single repo). As stated in [GitHub own docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-an-issues-only-repository):

> GitHub does not provide issues-only access permissions, but you can
>   accomplish this using a second repository which contains only the
>   issues.

However, please read the last paragraph:

> For example, if you pushed a commit to the private repository's
>   default branch with a message that read `Fixes organization/public-repo#12`
>   , the issue would be closed, but only users
>   with the proper permissions would see the cross-repository reference
>   indicating the commit that closed the issue. Without the permissions,
>   a reference still appears, but the details are omitted.

More on [how to link a pull request to an issue](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue) and/or [automatically closing issues with keywords in commit message](https://saraford.net/2017/02/15/how-to-automatically-close-issues-when-you-push-a-commit-to-github-046/).

Comment: maybe website or tools that show all github issues by token and can do action on them? you know something like this?

Comment: Please see my edit. You can automatically close issues from private on public so your dev overhead is reduced. So, basically, GitHub itself is the tool you want.